# MSSQL Issue Hibernate Criteria

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am using Java-Hibernate with two Databases (Postgresql and MSSQL).
SqlServer2012 with dialect:

```
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

I have written a Criteria query like :

```
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria=DetachedCriteria.forClass(entityClazz);
ProjectionList proj = Projections.projectionList();
proj.add(Projections.max(COMPOSEDID_VERSION_ID));
proj.add(Projections.groupProperty(COMPOSEDID_ID));
detachedCriteria.setProjection(proj);

criteria = session.createCriteria(entityClazz)
            .add( Subqueries.propertiesIn(new String[] { COMPOSEDID_VERSION_ID, COMPOSEDID_ID }, detachedCriteria));
```

This query worked fine with Postgre Db. But when i switch to MSSQL i get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:505)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:1029)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)[201:org.hibernate.core:5.0.0.Final]
```

Can anyone help me out? What change should i made in Criteria API to achieve my goal to get maxVersion record against each Id??

Comment: Did you turn on show_queries to look at what it's trying to do? That may help. See https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-debugging-where-does

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding subqueries in criteria of projections from detached critaria, add projection directly in critaria like this:

```
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria=DetachedCriteria.forClass(entityClazz);
ProjectionList proj = Projections.projectionList();
proj.add(Projections.max(COMPOSEDID_VERSION_ID));
proj.add(Projections.groupProperty(COMPOSEDID_ID));


criteria = session.createCriteria(entityClazz)
.setProjection( proj );
```

Comment: This method is fine for simple straight query  I was trying to achieve it for WHERE-IN clause for more than one column which MSSQL does not support.